# How to fix upload file from angular 7 to django rest

Tags: django, angular7

I'have rest api devlopped with djago and application front devlopped with agular7 and i try to upload image to my rest api when i try to send it with form data the form data is empty in the api.

for angular i try to send form data with file.

```
Angular:
   getPredictionImage(file): Observable<any> {
      const HttpUploadOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
      }
      const f = new FormData();
      f.append('image', file, file.name);
      console.log(f);
      return this.http.post(this.urlapiimage, file, HttpUploadOptions);
    }
```

```
Django:
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print("heloooo")
        print(request.data)
        serializer = MammographySerializer(data=request.data)
        print(serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            result='hi'
            serializer.save()
            return Response(result,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

the request.data is empty

Comment: does console.log print the correct image ?

Comment: if i print file : File {name: "general diagramme (11).png", lastModified: 156192837115......} 
but if i print formData : FormData {}

Comment: why don't you check your backend using a different client such as postman or good old curl? if your backend is working, then ... the problem is in the transport. else, the problem is with your backend.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me may be this help u to find your solution

```
Angular :
upload(file): Observable<any> {
  let csrftoken  = getCookie('csrftoken');
  let headers = new HttpHeaders({

    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,

  });
  const formdata = new FormData();
   formdata.append("image", file); //i did not use 3rd argument file.name
  let options = {
    headers: headers,  withCredentials :true  } 
  return this.http.post(this.urlapiimage , formdata,  options )

}

Django:
    def post(self, request, format=None):
       if 'file' not in request.data:
            raise ParseError("Empty content ")

        photo = request.data["file"]
        serializer = MammographySerializer(photo = photo) // use this instead data =request.data
        if serializer.is_valid():
            result='hi'
            serializer.save()
            return Response(result,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

after trying this , than also u r getting error , read about DRF parser ( https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/)

"**important point if u r using chrome and if r using http://127.0.0.1:8000/ for django server and localhost:4200/ for angular than because of CORS(different ports)  chrome does not allow . use this  127.0.0.1:4200/ for angular server instead of localhost:4200/ and if u don't want to do this use firefox instead of chrome it allows CORS**